# How to get View data in Laravel in custom helper or directive

Tags: php, laravel

I need to get all View data passed from controller in custom helper or directive, which was called in this View blade template.

So in blade template there is translation:

```
@lang($periodName . '.H1 title', ['time' => $time])
```

I want to make it shorter. For this purpose I created helper **periodTrans**('H1 Title').

```php
function periodTrans($title) {
 return __($periodName . '.' . $title,  ['time' => $time]);
}
```

It there is a way to get acces inside helper function to **$periodName** and **$time** variables, to not pass them like arguments and make function shorter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK this should work.

In your `controller`:

```php
public function __construct()
{
    .....
    \View::share('periodName', $periodName);
    \View::share('time', $time);
}
```

Your helper:

```
function periodTrans($title) {
    $data = \View::getShared(); 
    return __($data['periodName'] . '.' . $title,  ['time' => $data['time']]);
}
```